# django + confusion with the ORM

Tags: django, amazon-rds

I am getting a strange error despite following the documentation. I have the following model:

```
class UserToken(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Whenever I do `UserToken.objects.get(token=tokenValue)` (tokenValue is the value I am looking for) locally for MySQL, everything works. I get the value as expected. But when I do the same on my MySQL instance in Amazon RDS, I keep getting the following error:

`ERROR Unknown exception: UserToken matching query does not exist.`

Is there anything I am missing here? Why would a statement like this not work in RDS?

**[EDIT]**

Just to clarify, the token values do indeed exist. I checked the database just to make sure. Also I tried the following:

`ut = UserToken.objects.raw("select * from user_token")` (just to test..there was only one entry in the table) and i'm getting the following error: `Unknown exception: 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'token'`. Is there a reason for this? The `token` field does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure how this is different...but previously I was doing `request.raw_post_data` to get the json message that the user was sending me. I changed that to `request.POST` and `request.body` and somehow that fixed the issue. Just in case anybody else faces this hard-to-debug issue!